# Pie Charts in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, pie-chart

Im trying to create a pie chart and have seen many different ways of doing so. I am trying to do it with the seemingly simplest method that I could find however I cannot get it to work. My code is below

```
     If chkboxPieChart.CheckState = True Then
            Dim percents() As Decimal = {EStock, EWages, EAdvertising, ERent, EElectricity, ERepayments, EPackaging}
            Dim colors() As Color = {Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Red, Color.Orange, Color.Purple, Color.Azure, Color.Chartreuse}
            Dim graphics As Graphics = Me.picboxPieChart.CreateGraphics
            Dim location As Point = New Point(462, 257)
            Dim size As Size = New Size(200, 200)
            DrawPieChart(percents, colors, graphics, location, size)
        End If
```

With this being the code for the DrawPieChart Sub

```
    Public Sub DrawPieChart(ByVal percents() As Decimal, ByVal colors() As Color, ByVal surface As Graphics, ByVal location As Point, ByVal pieSize As Size)
    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    For Each percent As Integer In percents
        sum += percent
    Next
    Dim percentTotal As Integer = 0
    For percent As Integer = 0 To percents.Length() - 1
        surface.FillPie(New SolidBrush(colors(percent)), New Rectangle(location, pieSize), CType(percentTotal * 360 / 100, Single), CType(percents(percent) * 360 / 100, Single))
        percentTotal += percents(percent)
    Next
    Return
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Either draw in the `Paint` event and use the `e.Graphics` object or be sure to dispose your `CreateGrahics` object.

Comment: @OneFineDay Sorry what youve said is probably obvious and easy to unnderstand but I'm not entirely sure what you mean or how to go about it

Comment: The `PictureBox` has a `Paint` event. You should be using that. [Here](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/gdi-pie-chart-in-vb.net) is link to an example of using `GDI+`, which is what your doing, and may help you out.